# JAVA Google Analytics GA4 API Issue

Tags: google-analytics-4

"I am working with the Java language, currently transitioning from Universal Analytics (UA) to Google Analytics 4 (GA4). I am encountering an issue while setting up GoogleCredentials. The behavior differs when I access it through Tomcat compared to when I access it using @Test. What should I check in this situation?"

check JUNIT4, Tomcat 8.5